# Z-index issues not sure what to do now

Tags: html, css, layout

How do i make the `h1` and `img` elements "appear" ontop of the opaque div they are contained in? I mean, how do I make it look like they are not being affected by the opaque-ness of their parent div?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXE39/2/):

```
<div id="main">
<div id="seethru">
       <img ... />
       <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>
</div>

#main { 
   background-color: green;
}
#seethru { 
   width: auto; 
   height: auto; 
   opacity: 0.4; 
   background-color: blue; 
}
#seethru img, h1 { 
   position: relative; 
   z-index: 9999; 
   color: white; 
}
```

So far nothing is working, and I can't separate this content, it must be inside the opaque div

Comment: your div must need color?

Comment: @Raymond, definitely. My div needs to be a certain color so the page as the effect I'm going for.

Comment: This link might help you http://biostall.com/only-applying-a-css-opacity-to-the-parent-container

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `opacity` property which will make it's child elements opaque too, so in order to prevent that use `rgba(0, 0, 255, .4)` and that will prevent child elements to get opaque.

Explanation for `rgba` : `rgba()` is nothing but pure `rgb(red, green, blue)` but with an additional parameter of `a` which is alpha, nothing but opacity, so you can use this as an alternative when you are dealing with background colors

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dXE39/3/)

There are few workarounds where you can prevent child elements from getting opaque, for [example](http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/)

For details on browser support of [`rgba`](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) (For IE, you can use [CSS3 Pie)](http://css3pie.com/)

> Note: When you use `background-color: rgba()` always remember to use a
>   fall back color declared using a `hex` or pure `rgb` so that
>   non-supportive browsers won't fail to render at least the base color
>   but without opacity, alternatively you can also use transparent png's as a
>   background with `background-repeat` property(But this is 90's way to
>   do) ;)

As [@Adrift Commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683316/z-index-issues-not-sure-what-to-do-now/16683342?noredirect=1#comment24008699_16683342), You can read [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-css3-color-20080721/#transparency), why actually the child elements get opaque too

Comment: Thank you Mr Alien, does this work just as well as opacity across different browsers?

Comment: @Joey You welcome :) I'll add the support for this property in my answer soon

Comment: [Opacity](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-css3-color-20080721/#transparency) actually isn't inherited - instead a container elements' content is affected because a value less than 1 is composited from a *single* offscreen image. The [color module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-css3-color-20080721/) also gives an explanation: `"If the object is a container element, then the effect is as if the contents of the container element were blended against the current background using a mask where the value of each pixel of the mask is <alphavalue>.`"

Comment: @Adrift I used the wrong word here :) thanks for pointing it out, I've edited my answer, feel free to edit if you think am missing something here

Answer (score 0):

internet explorer up to IE8 doesn't supports the RGBA colors. So it would be better if you place h1 and img element outside the opaque div and then move it visually inside using CSS positioning.

Check out this great tutorial it will certainly solve your problem.

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-opacity.php